# How can I see rendered MathJax/LaTeX when reviewing edits?

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, review

Posts from new users often requiring edits that add LaTeX code. When I review edits from users that add such code, all I see on the LHS and RHS are the raw LaTeX codes, such as `$a_y=g$`. This is the case even after I select the "rendered" view button. I'd rather just compare the two rendered outputs. Admittedly I have only noticed this on my Mac's Safari, and haven't tried other browsers.

Is there a way to view rendered LaTeX when reviewing?

Comment: Sometimes it takes a moment or two for me to get them to load (using Opera 12 webbrowser on Scientific Linux 6.4), I usually just run with it and fix it after submitting the fix (you get a 5 minute grace period anyway)

Answer (score 3):

You mean like the third paragraph in [this edit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/35315)?

[image: Screenshot]

That's kind of a tricky case.  The problem is that the change is *in the middle of* an equation, so the diff engine sticks some extra markup in there to highlight it, causing MathJax not to recognize it as a valid equation at all.  To fix it, either:

- a) the SE diff generator would need be changed to treat MathJax sections as atomic blocks (which would have the unfortunate side effect of always showing the entire equation as changed, even if the actual change was to a tiny part of it), or
- b) MathJax itself would have to be somehow tweaked to recognize the diff markup and replicate it in the rendered equation.  [I've done a bit of MathJax hacking myself](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4130/the-scope-of-newcommand-is-the-entire-page/12502#12502), but that sounds way beyond my skills.

I suspect the first option above would be the more practical one, but I can't really tell — AFAIK, the diff generation is done on the server side, so only SE developers actually know how the code works.

Answer (score 1):

I just run the [chatjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/should-chat-have-tex-support) bookmarklet on the diff. It usually works.

I guess showing a rendered diff of math is a rather non-trivial problem, so they just show the latex diff.

Comment: For me it fails to render when VTCing as a duplicate: the original renders but the duplicates don't. I'll give this a try and see if it works.

Comment: Does this fix [my problem](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4393/parsing-of-revisions-involving-insertion-of-dollar-signs)?

Comment: @ChrisWhite I don't think so :/

Comment: @EmilioPisanty: [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) includes a fix for [that problem](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/537/missing-mathjax-in-the-duplicate-subtab-of-the-close-review-queue).